# What is the difference between packages in jammy and jammy-updates?

Tags: apt, 22.04

I upgraded today my laptop from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 (Jammy). After this update, I noticed I was affected by a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1971693) in `mutter` 42.0 that was fixed in 42.1-0ubuntu1. However `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` doesn’t upgrade the package.

The new version doesn’t show up anywhere even if that bug was fixed almost one year ago.

```
$ apt policy mutter
mutter:
  Installed: 42.0-3ubuntu2
  Candidate: 42.0-3ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 42.0-3ubuntu2 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Looking at the [packages for `jammy`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mutter) the version is indeed still `42.0-3ubuntu2`. But in the [packages for `jammy-updates`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/mutter), the version is `42.5-0ubuntu1`.

What is this `jammy-updates`? I couldn’t find anything online about this. How can I use this packages source and so get the updated `mutter` package?